# Unique index or primary key violation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Estou recebendo o erro abaixo ao tentar criar um novo item em uma tabela, nesta tabela possuo alguns itens previamente adicionados.

```
2019-03-17 00:05:09 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-03-17 00:05:09 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3 ON PUBLIC.LOJA_DOCUMENTO(ID_DOCUMENTO) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
/* insert br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento */ insert into loja_documento (codigo_documento, descricao_documento, id_pessoa, valor_documento, id_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-198]
2019-03-17 00:05:09 ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019-03-17 00:05:09 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3 ON PUBLIC.LOJA_DOCUMENTO(ID_DOCUMENTO) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
/* insert br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento */ insert into loja_documento (codigo_documento, descricao_documento, id_pessoa, valor_documento, id_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-198]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3 ON PUBLIC.LOJA_DOCUMENTO(ID_DOCUMENTO) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
/* insert br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento */ insert into loja_documento (codigo_documento, descricao_documento, id_pessoa, valor_documento, id_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-198]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
```

Meu Model é esse:

```
package br.com.odin.loja.backend.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "loja_documento")
public class Documento {

    // Attributes
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, precision = 3, scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO", allocationSize=1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CODIGO_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "VALOR_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String valor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "documentos", allowSetters = true)
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    // Constructors

    // Getters & Setters
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    // Methods

}
```

Até onde pude entender eu estou tentando adicionar o id 1 na tabela porém esse id ja existe na tabela. Não sei como fazer o hibernate entender que é para pegar o próximo valor da lista. Agradeço desde já.

Atenciosamente, 
Eduardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que você já tem dados previamente persistidos nessa tabela, identifique qual o maior `id` adicionado atualmente nessa tabela e use a propriedade `initialValue` a partir desse valor, por exemplo:

```
Select max(id) from table
```

Se o maior `id` da sua tabela for `4`, você utilizará `initialValue = 5`:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO", initialValue = 5, allocationSize = 1)
```

Teste também mover a anotação `@SequenceGenerator` pra cima da declaração da classe:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "loja_documento")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO", initialValue = 5, allocationSize = 1)
public class Documento {
```

Apesar das recomendações, caso te interesse você pode substituir sua `strategy` por `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY`. Esta fará com que o *spring* gerenciei o `id` pelo `auto_increment` do banco. Assim você não terá esse problema de gerar um `id` que já existe no banco.

No caso ficaria assim:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, precision = 3, scale = 0)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

Recomendo que você teste uma das recomendações de cada vez.

> [Referência Universidade Java](http://www.universidadejava.com.br/materiais/jpa-sequence/)
>
> [Referência DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/jpa-como-usar-a-anotacao-generatedvalue/38592)

Comment: Excelente, o initial value ja funcionou. Mas no meu data.sql, utilizei o nextVal do banco de dados para alterar a sequence e atualizar ela.